# Offer app-settings / -menu in Android TV app

Tags: android, settings, television

Are there best practices for an Android TV app to offer its app settings?
In some cases there may be a hardware button available for settings (as on some remotes),
but on most remotes there is not - how can the app properly offer app settings?
What button combination is the default one for showing the app menu or its settings?